# Failure while connecting Spring Boot to PostgreSql database using JPA/Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to access a `PostgreSQL DB` from `Spring-Boot application using JPA/Hibernate`

The Spring-Boot application consists of a `RestController` which on user events on certain URL, will connect to PostgreSQL DB and add an entry in DB.

To communicate with the PostgreSQL DB, the RestController uses a Spring service instance, whose class autowires a JPARepository.

For the PostgreSQL DB, I have defined a DBConfig class which is annotated with Spring `@Configuration` and has a `createDataSource()` method (see below).

I have not defined any DBConnection class as `@Configuration` **OR** haven't specified any JDBC connection as `@Bean` in my DBConfig class because I am assuming that adding `@Configuration` to the DBConfig will add the connection configuration in Spring `ApplicationContext` using the `application.properties` file under classpath.

**Do I need to define a separate connection bean inside the DBConfig class? *OR*
Do I need to define a DBConnection class separately?**

**Do I need to define connection properties both at DataSource.setJdbcUrl(String) and src/main/resources/application.properties or any one of the two?**

**Do I need to add any extra dependency other than the ones already listed below in pom.xml?**

**How to specify and create the connection to PostgreSQL DB from Spring-Boot?**

**Am I missing any configuration here? (as I am new to Spring JPA/Hibernate)**

> DBConfig class

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource;

@Configuration
public class DBConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource createDataSource() throws Exception {
        ComboPooledDataSource ds = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db?user=postgres_user&password=password");
        ds.setDriverClass("org.postgresql.Driver");
        return ds;
    }
}
```

It is a Spring Service class, with the autowired repository instance to deal with the PostgreSQL DB

> ServiceImpl class with JPARepository Instance (autowired)

```
@Service("webhookService")
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceImpl.class);

       @Autowired
       private MyRepository myRepository;

       //methods for dealing with DB e.g. find, add, delete, update, etc.

}
```

> My Spring-Boot RestController class

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

       private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyController.class);

       @Autowired
       MyService myService;
```

> src/main/resources/application.properties

```
#Datasource properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres_user 
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop

#Hibernate properties
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

> Spring-Boot-data / JPA / PostgreSQL dependencies (from pom.xml)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

> Error Stacktrace while deploying .WAR on Tomcat

```
2017-12-28 11:25:56.281  WARN 3101 --- [HelperThread-#0] c.m.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool    : com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@1d7cb052 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2654) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1771) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:39) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:211) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1773) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:263) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:775) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.<init>(NewPooledConnection.java:120) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:181) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:147) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:202) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696) [mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar:0.2.11]

2017-12-28 11:25:56.282  WARN 3101 --- [HelperThread-#0] c.m.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool    : Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@25e78fee is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
2017-12-28 11:25:56.282  WARN 3101 --- [HelperThread-#2] c.m.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool    : com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@61136ebb -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2654) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1771) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:39) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:211) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1773) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:263) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:775) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.<init>(NewPooledConnection.java:120) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:181) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:147) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:202) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696) [mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar:0.2.11]

2017-12-28 11:25:56.293  WARN 3101 --- [HelperThread-#2] c.m.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool    : Having failed to acquire a resource, com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@25e78fee is interrupting all Threads waiting on a resource to check out. Will try again in response to new client requests.
2017-12-28 11:25:56.311  WARN 3101 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:339) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:366) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup.getDatabase(DatabaseLookup.java:72) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties.determineDatabase(JpaProperties.java:139) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter(JpaBaseConfiguration.java:105) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee7fda69.CGLIB$jpaVendorAdapter$4(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee7fda69$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$40f1d36d.invoke(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ee7fda69.jpaVendorAdapter(<generated>) [spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:835) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:467) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:87) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:986) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857) [catalina.jar:8.5.24]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.JdbcUtils.extractDatabaseMetaData(JdbcUtils.java:326) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        ... 74 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
        at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar:0.2.11]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:692) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
        ... 75 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1469) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:644) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:554) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:758) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:685) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This ResultSet is closed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.checkClosed(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:2654) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.setFetchSize(AbstractJdbc2ResultSet.java:1771) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement.createResultSet(Jdbc4Statement.java:39) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$StatementResultHandler.handleResultRows(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:211) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1773) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:374) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.execSQLUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:263) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.getTransactionIsolation(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:775) ~[postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar:na]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection.<init>(NewPooledConnection.java:120) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:181) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:147) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:202) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1138) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1125) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$700(BasicResourcePool.java:44) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1870) ~[c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar:0.9.5.2]
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:696) ~[mchange-commons-java-0.2.11.jar:0.2.11]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to define a @Configuration or Datasource for your Postgres database. If you are using the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency and the Postgres Java driver is also on your classpath (include it in your `pom.xml`, Spring will automatically connect your application to your database. So just define the connection string in your `application.properties` and remove your @Configuration class.

Your Repository can look like the following:

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<YourClass, Long>{

   // Spring gives your all the basic CRUD operations per default

}
```

or if you want to use JpaRepository :

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<YourClass, Long>{

   // Spring gives your all the basic database operations per default

}
```

If you need an example project, have a look at: https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-postgress-example/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks I added only the application.properties and removed the `@Configuration` class. Also, in my case, the port `8080` had to be opened, since it was closed. Btw, I guess you could have annotated the `MyRepository` class with `@Repository` and added `@EnableJpaRepositiries(cannonical package name for repository class)` at `SpringBootApplication` class.